# Read current git branch natively using vscode extension

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

While I am developing an extension for Visual Studio Code (vscode) I have asked myself how to proper read git refs like the current branch using native methods.

My current solutions feels more like a workaround:

- fetch the git path
- run `git rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'`
- return stdout as string and put into variable (E.g. master)

Complete method implemented [here](https://github.com/ole1986/gitHistoryVSCode/blob/log-by-branch/src/helpers/gitPaths.ts#L147) (forked extension gitHistoryVSCode)

Any other ideas, for example how to access the extension/git methods or model properties?

Comment: I issued this on github to maybe provide a git scm API explained in the following link: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native git extension now provides several methods / properties to fetch the current branch as well as all branches

Check out the git extension api reference here:

**get branch**
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/git/src/api/api1.ts#L160

**get branches**
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/git/src/api/api1.ts#L164

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to [follow the setup instructions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/08d383346c18f6b20cb74219611f7c1b590c35b1/extensions/git/README.md#git-integration-for-visual-studio-code).

Then, [here's what I came up with](https://github.com/walles/git-commit-message-plus/blob/83bebe0321e99f616a08d9a043f2cdd790d5e26b/src/extension.ts#L82-L118).

```js
function getCurrentGitBranch(docUri: vscode.Uri): string | undefined {
  const extension = vscode.extensions.getExtension<GitExtension>("vscode.git");
  if (!extension) {
    console.warn("Git extension not available");
    return undefined;
  }
  if (!extension.isActive) {
    console.warn("Git extension not active");
    return undefined;
  }

  // "1" == "Get version 1 of the API". Version one seems to be the latest when I
  // type this.
  const git = extension.exports.getAPI(1);
  const repository = git.getRepository(docUri);
  if (!repository) {
    console.warn("No Git repository for current document", docUri);
    return undefined;
  }

  const currentBranch = repository.state.HEAD;
  if (!currentBranch) {
    console.warn("No HEAD branch for current document", docUri);
    return undefined;
  }

  const branchName = currentBranch.name;
  if (!branchName) {
    console.warn("Current branch has no name", docUri, currentBranch);
    return undefined;
  }

  return branchName;
}
```